# Splitting Python string into list of pairs

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have data in the following format:

```
"22.926 g 47.377 g 73.510 g 131.567 g 322.744 g"
```

What I would like to do is to split it into a list such that value and units are grouped together, e.g.:

```
["22.926 g","47.377 g","73.510 g","131.567 g","322.744 g"]
```

Of course, in Python 2.7, I can do this the hard way:

```
result = []
tokens = "22.926 g 47.377 g 73.510 g 131.567 g 322.744 g".split()
for index,item in enumerate(tokens[::2]):
    result.append(item+" "+tokens[index+1])
```

but I hoped that there is a slightly more elegant way for doing this?

Comment: Regular Expressions would be a neater way. I'll see if I can get something working and if so post it as an answer

Comment: Will the units always be 'g', or will you need to deal with other unit strings?

Comment: Ideally, other units should be supported, but they will always be in the form with a g at the end, e.g. mg or kg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = "22.926 g 47.377 g 73.510 g 131.567 g 322.744 g".split()
c = [" ".join((v, g)) for v,g in zip(a[:-1:2], a[1::2])]
```

Comment: that doesn't give the expected result: `['22.926 g',
 'g 47.377',
 '47.377 g',
 'g 73.510',
 '73.510 g',
 'g 131.567',
 '131.567 g',
 'g 322.744',
 '322.744 g']`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the step. Updated

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, very nice!

Answer (score 4):

With regex (and the [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.findall) method)you could obtain what you need :

```
import re
text="22.926 g 47.377 g 73.510 g 131.567 g 322.744 g"
re.findall("\d+\.\d+ g", text)
>>>['22.926 g', '47.377 g', '73.510 g', '131.567 g', '322.744 g']
```

But keep in mind that when solving a problem with regex we often end with 2 problems ;)

Comment: I was far too slow to post my answer!

Answer (score 2):

In one-line! Split the string, and use list comprehension to get the desired output by removing all `g` and appending `g`!

```
s="22.926 g 47.377 g 73.510 g 131.567 g 322.744 g"
>>> [x+' g' for x in s.split() if x!='g']
```

Output

```
['22.926 g', '47.377 g', '73.510 g', '131.567 g', '322.744 g']
```

Answer (score 2):

what about splitting according to `" g"` and strip/filter out empty fields, re-add the `g` suffix afterwards, in one line:

```
["{} g".format(x.strip()) for x in "22.926 g 47.377 g 73.510 g 131.567 g 322.744 g".split(" g") if x]
```

result:

```
['22.926 g', '47.377 g', '73.510 g', '131.567 g', '322.744 g']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = "22.926 g 47.377 g 73.510 g 131.567 g 322.744 g"
sep = 'g'
result = ['{digit} {sep}'.format(digit=d.strip(), sep=sep) for d in data[:-1].split(sep)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but how about:

```
s = "22.926 g 47.377 g 73.510 g 131.567 g 322.744 g"
l = s.strip('g').split('g')
l = [item + 'g' for item in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most beautiful way but it's a one-line solution:

```
[s.lstrip() + "g" for s in text.split("g") if s]
```

Comment: what are `tokens` here?

Comment: @VanPeer I changed `tokens` by `text`, so it's clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is something wrong with your solution, but the usual approach would probably consists of a [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

```
import re

input = "22.926 g 47.377 g 73.510 g 131.567 g 322.744 g"
result = p.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+ g)', input)
print(result)
```

prints

```
['22.926 g', '47.377 g', '73.510 g', '131.567 g', '322.744 g']
```

Comment: Yeah, just noticed. I will leave it because mine includes a link to a tutorial, just in case OP doesn't know what regular expressions are.