# Parsing associate array returned from TCL in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tcl, associative-array

I am having one requirement for calling TCL scripts from Python. My requirement is to call a TCL proc from python. The TCL proc returns the result as an array. I need to parse the returned array in Python to form a dictionary. Below is a working code. Is there any more efficient way to do the same?

Python Code

```
import tkinter
import shlex

r=tkinter.Tk()
r.tk.eval('source proc.tcl')
arr = []
arr = r.tk.eval('processarray arr')
print(arr)
j=0
for i in arr.split(' '):
    print(i)
d = {}
ssplit = arr.split()
print(len(ssplit))
print(len(ssplit)/2)
j=int(len(ssplit)/2)
k=0
for i in range (j):
    key = ssplit[k]
    d[key] = ssplit[k+1]
    k += 2
print(d)
```

TCL Code

```
proc processarray { $arr } {
    array set arr " arrlist 25645"
    set arr(0) "11"
    set arr(1) "10"
    set arr(2) "20"
    set arr(3) "30"
    set arr(4) "40"
    return [array get arr]
}
```

Expected Result

```
{'4': '40', '0': '11', '1': '10', 'arrlist': '25645', '2': '20', '3': '30'}
```

Comment: how looks this array when you get from TCL ?

Comment: you have wrong indentations in code - correct it. We can't test code when it has incorrect indentations.

Comment: show in question what result do you expect.

Comment: TCL returns a space separated string as below

`4 40 0 11 1 10 arrlist 25645 2 20 3 30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used TCL but I run this code and get from TCL

```
4 40 0 11 1 10 arrlist 25645 2 20 3 30
```

I can convert it to dictionary using `range(len())` and `[i:i+2]`.
Maybe it is not popular to use `range(len())` but in this situation it will be very useful.

```
import tkinter

r = tkinter.Tk()
r.tk.eval('source proc.tcl')

arr = []
arr = r.tk.eval('processarray arr')
#print(arr)

items = arr.split()

data = {}
for i in range(0, len(items), 2):
    key, val = items[i:i+2]
    data[key] = val
    
print(data)
```

Result

```
{'4': '40', '0': '11', '1': '10', 'arrlist': '25645', '2': '20', '3': '30'}
```

---

**EDIT:** I can do this also with `iter()` and `zip()`

```
import tkinter

r = tkinter.Tk()
r.tk.eval('source proc.tcl')

arr = []
arr = r.tk.eval('processarray arr')
#print(arr)

items = arr.split()

data = {}
it = iter(items) # create iterator 

for key, val in zip(it, it):  # use `zip()` to get two elements from list
    data[key] = val
    
print(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Python's Tkinter package isn't documented very well, so I had to dig into the source for this...

There is a `_splitdict()` function that will, given a string with an even number of tcl words like that returned by Tcl's `array get`, return it as a python dictionary. I don't really know Python, but I bet the underscore and clunky interface means it's internal and you're not supposed to use it. But there doesn't seem to be a public alternative:

```py
>>> import tkinter
>>> tcl = tkinter.Tcl()
>>> tkinter._splitdict(tcl, 'foo 1 bar 2 baz {3 4}')
{'bar': '2', 'foo': '1', 'baz': '3 4'}
```

Alternatively, you can probably just write your function that does what it does internally. The important bit is the `tk.splitlist('some string')`, which breaks its argument up into words according to tcl rules - needed to properly handle spaces or anything like that in the individual words of the list that `array get` returns (See above for an example).

A (Untested), trimmed down version. Original can be found [in the Python source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L123)

```py
def splitdict(v):
    """Return a properly formatted dict built from Tcl list pairs.
    Tcl list is expected to contain an even number of elements.
    """
    t = r.tk.splitlist(v)
    if len(t) % 2:
        raise RuntimeError('Tcl list representing a dict is expected '
                           'to contain an even number of elements')
    it = iter(t)
    dict = {}
    for key, value in zip(it, it):
        key = str(key)
        dict[key] = value
    return dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things for yourself a lot by using `call` instead of `eval`.

```
import tkinter

r = tkinter.Tk()
# Putting the Tcl code I've used inline
r.tk.eval("""
    proc processarray { $arr } {
        array set arr " arrlist 25645"
        set arr(0) "11"
        set arr(1) "10"
        set arr(2) "20"
        set arr(3) "30"
        set arr(4) "40"
        # CRITICAL! Must return a list, not a dict
        return [list {*}[array get arr]]
    }
""")
r.tk.wantobjects(True)  # This is the default setting...
arr = r.tk.call('processarray', 'arr')
# This is a bit of magic to turn a pair-list into a dict, based on
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202751/splitting-python-string-into-list-of-pairs
c = {k: v for k, v in zip(arr[:-1:2], arr[1::2])}
print(c)
```

The critical things here are that:

1. we use `call` (which is a better option for calling single commands and does argument boundary preservation, etc.),
2. we've got `wantobjects(True)` (actually on by default), and
3. we get the Tcl side to force the result to be a list (`[list {*}…]`) ***and*** we post-process that list on the Python side to get a dictionary (this is because Tkinter doesn't do dict mapping for you for some reason; that's a Tkinter bug/missing feature).

When I run this, I get this output:

```
{4: '40', 0: '11', 1: '10', 'arrlist': '25645', 2: '20', 3: '30'}
```

That's as expected; Tcl's arrays have never been order-preserving and are documented to not be so. (I've no idea why Tkinter's converted some keys to `int`s.)